# Ruby on Rails - Creating Wrong Schema.rb File?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rake, migrate

Am I correct in saying that the db/schema.rb file should be pulling from the db/migrate files on rake db:migrate?  I am running a rake db:migrate and it is adding a table that isn't defined in the migrate, nor the models.  Any ideas?

Migrate Files (just one):

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :hashed_password
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Resulting Schema after rake:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20121113214159) do

  create_table "user_categories", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "description"

    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "hashed_password"

    t.datetime "created_at",                  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                  :null => false
  end

end
```

I had added a user_categories scaffolding earlier, but incorrectly so I destroyed it. Not sure where I went wrong in destroying parts...

Comment: Can you show your schema and your migrate files

Comment: There it is -- sorry about that.  Also, mentioned that I had actually created the scaffolding earlier, but I destroyed it.  It wouldn't be reading the database would it?  I'm using SQLite and I was getting errors earlier about a table existing, but it wouldn't let me drop it.

Comment: If you don't have any important data on your db, you could run `rake db:drop` then `rake db:create`. Then run `rake db:migrate` and it should update your schema clean.

Comment: That worked!  Not quite sure why rake db:migrate reads the database... shouldn't it just read the migrate files?

Comment: rake db:migrate doesn't read the database per say. If you see on the schema file it has a version. That version matches the timestamp for the latest migration. Migrations earlier than your schema version won't be read to update db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have any important data on your db, you could run `rake db:drop` then `rake db:create`. Then run `rake db:migrate` and it should update your schema clean.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to note that `rake db:migrate` will poll your database for its current state (separate of migrations) and update schema.rb accordingly. If you go into SQL command line and add a table, for example, and then run `rake db:migrate`, schema.rb will reflect that new table whether there's a migration or not.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that your forgot to define environment variables.

1. Open `Gemfile` and verify that you don't use the `sqlite` gem for your environment
2. Type the `rake db:drop` then `rake db:drop` commands if as output you receive empty string probably you forgot to setup environment variables
3. Checkout the `config/database.yml` file and find places where you could use them. You should find something like that: `database: <%= ENV["<DB_NAME"] %>`
4. Ensure that your variables has been set before. If you use the `dotenv` or `figaro` gems, probably you forgot to create appropriate file or define variables there